# R text substitution in odbc sqlquery

Tags: r

I'm trying to use text substitutes in R to put in custom dates with my SQL odbc connect query.

For example, I could change date1 to be 2016-01-31 and the data would automatically execute. However, using bquote text replacement, it doesn't seem to work....

Any ideas?

```
library("rodbc")
date1 <- c("2016-12-31")

myconn <- odbcConnect("edwPROD",uid="username",pwd="BBBBB")
data1 <- sqlQuery(myconn,"
SELECT  a.*
    FROM (SELECT id
                ,status_code                
                ,rate_plan
                ,publication
                ,active_count
                FROM prod_view.fct_active
                WHERE snap_start_date<=bquote(.date1)
                ) AS a  
")
odbcClose(myconn)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for package `infuser`. It allows you to change one part of the SQL request, in this case `date1`.

```
library(infuser)
date1 <- c("2016-12-31")

sql_query_template <- "SELECT  a.*
    FROM (SELECT id
                ,status_code
                ,rate_plan
                ,publication
                ,active_count
                FROM prod_view.fct_active
                WHERE snap_start_date<='{{date1}}'
                ) AS a;"
sql_query <-infuse(sql_query_template, date1=date1)

myconn <- odbcConnect("edwPROD",uid="username",pwd="BBBBB")
data1 <- sqlQuery(myconn,sql_query)
odbcClose(myconn)
```

Comment: hi how do we change the variable identifier? I'm thinking of using changing it to look like SAS macro with &variable. eventually i would like to build a function around it